# Starting VM instance "instance-1" failed. Error: [nvidia-tesla-t4] features are not compatible for creating instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gpu, nvidia, gcloud

After stopping my instance I am getting the following error:

```
Starting VM instance "instance-1" failed. Error: [nvidia-tesla-t4] features are not compatible for creating instance.
```

and I cannot start my instance back. When I try to connect using gcloud console

```
(gcloud.compute.instances.get-serial-port-output) Could not fetch serial port output: The resource is not ready.
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message, it means the (NVIDIA TESLA t4) is currently not available(not supported) in the zone? This is an expected behavior as you can find the details of alternative GPU models and their current available zones here[1]. 
As a workaround, you may try creating the GCE VM in a different zone. You can see[1] the zones currently supporting NVIDIA TESLA t-4 GPU.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#gpus-list

Comment: Just some UI weirdness to be aware of: if you're switching an existing VM to a GPU, the cloud console shows GPUs as available for regions that they're not available in (and then gives you this error message when you try to save your edits). Creating a new instance gives you a much clearer error about what regions are/aren't available.